# load a webpage in a webview vb

Tags: vb.net, webview, html

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

```
Private Sub WebView_NavigationCompleted()
    Dim uri As New Uri("google.com")
    webView1.Navigate(uri)
End Sub
```

End Class

I have a webview on my designer and I clicked on the webview to get the private sub above. However, when the app loads, it won't display the webpage. What am I doing wrong?
I wanted this app to view a single web page as soon as the app loads.

I have tried to look this up on google, but nothing is seeming to work.

Answer (score 1):

A Uri like that would, under normal circumstances, cause a System.UriFormatException (Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z6c2z492%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Try something like "http://www.google.com" instead.